# JavaScript Button Enable and Disable with PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have a while loop that fetches data from a database. I have made three buttons:

```
> Open  
> Hold   
> Close
```

The first time when the page loads, only the open button should be enabled, and the others should be disabled.

After I click the open button, the open button should be disabled,  and the hold and close buttons should be enabled.

I got this result for only one row, but in the while loop not for all the rows.

I have used JavaScript with php.

Example:

```
function onload()
{
    document.getElementById("Hold").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("close").disabled = true;
    return false; 
}
```

The above code was working for the first row, but I need it to work for all the while loop values.

Comment: Include a sample of your markup.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem lies in that you are using the same ID for multiple elements - ID's must be unique to each element, and thus, getElementById returns ONE element, with that ID. Give them classes instead.

Answer (score 2):

#### HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Open" id="openButton" name="openButton">
<input type="button" value="Hold" id="holdButton" name="holdButton" disabled="disabled">
<input type="button" value="Close" id="closeButton" name="closeButton" disabled="disabled">
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).on('click','input[type=button]', function() {
               buttonVal = $(this).val();
    if(buttonVal == 'Open' )
    {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        $('#holdButton,#closeButton').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else
    {
         $('#holdButton,#closeButton').prop("disabled", true);
         $('#openButton').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7gLRH/)